# getting undefined while accessing object properties in nodejs in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I'm building webapp using node and mongodb where i'm registering userdata  in one api and getting jwt token as response and passing that token in another api and retrieving user data while doing that i'm  able to get json object as response  but .I'm getting undefined while i try to access one of the json object using . notation
my response is printing like this

req.user is printing Object like below

{
"user": {
"_id": "5f0082efe997800c40115be1",
"name": "John Max",
"email": "John30@gmail.com"
},
"iat": 1593869039
}

req.user._id gives undefined
i tried accessing  like this req.user[_id] as well nothing works ! where req.user is of type of object

Answer (score 1):

without a clue on the code you used I'm probably wrong but :

- If when you log "req.user" you get { "user": { "_id": "5f0082efe997800c40115be1", "name": "John Max", "email": "John30@gmail.com" }, "iat": 1593869039 }, then you should access _id with : req.user.user._id (if I never saw this before I would'nt allow myself to suggest that ...)
- Maybe it's an issue about parsing the json ?

Comment: no @adzaria i have checked parsing json its working fine .and its of type object so json is parsed and printing fully but not able to access individual properties .

Comment: accessing like this works fine req.user.user._id .im able to get id can you explain how it works @adzaria

Comment: Hi ! I'm glad it works, actually you have stored your "user" object into another "user" object, without seeing your code it is hard to tell where it happens, but it's probably the way you store it the first time, if you post some code we can maybe check